# how to Change the text color of one column on datagrid when user enters data on other column

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, flexbuilder, flex4.6

I had a very simple problem that, I had a spark datagrid of 3 columns in which 2 columns will be with data and the third column is an empty column with text input as itemeditor. So what ever the data user enters in the cells of third column should always verify with the first column and the appropriate first column value or text should turn into red. This is because user should not enter the duplicate value.So,somebody please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Advanced datagrid` instead of `spark`, in `Advanced datagrid`, you can do this by using the `styleFunction="myStyleFunction"` of a data grid or a single column.

code sample:

```
public function myStyleFunc(data:Object, col:AdvancedDataGridColumn):Object
{
    // all rows for invalid selection combinations
    if ((data["isRequired"]) && !(data["isSelected"]))
        return {color:0xFF0000, fontWeight:"bold", backgroundColor:0xf2d6d7}; 

    // Return null if the selection is valid
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For coloring in datagrid column for best practice use itemrenderer there you can easily show color for background and foreground.
In case of text color in datagrid use this setStyle. e.g.

labelDisplay.setStyle("color",0xFFFFFF);

labelDisplay is the id of your Label inside itemrenderer.